# Friendly id don't change slug in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, globalization, friendly-id

I use the friendly_id gem for making slugs and globalize gem for translations in Rails but when I go to the show.html.erb and change the language the controller can't find the entry. My files are:

Category.rb model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string
#  description :text
#  slug        :string
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name

    translates :name, :description, :slug

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => [:slugged, :globalize]

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
   name_changed?
    end

    has_and_belongs_to_many :sponsors

  def name_with_initial
    "#{name}"
  end
end
```

categories_controller.rb (only the part where I try to find the category):

```
...
  private
  def set_category
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
  rescue
   flash[:alert] = "Category don't exist."
   redirect_to admin_categories_path
  end
...
```

When I change the locales on the index.html.erb everything is normal and I see the translations but when I'm on the show.html.erb page and than change  locales I get problems. 
I make first the en translation (default) and than the cz translation. Now when I got to:
http://localhost:3000/en/admin/categories/name-eng

than change to cz the link looks like:
http://localhost:3000/cz/admin/categories/name-eng

Only the locales changed but not the slug and there are no errors.

--- PROBLEM ---
When I go first to the cz variant the link:
http://localhost:3000/cz/admin/categories/name-cz

and than try to change to en I get error. Controller can't find it because it try to find the cz slug.

In the console when I change I18n the slugs are present.

Do you know why is this happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

--- EDIT ---
Works when I change

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

and the link to the show.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= link_to category.name, admin_category_path(:id => category.id) %>
```

But than I can't have te friendly id.

Comment: Not able to open ur link as u shared link with localhost link. Kindly give link with ur ip. :)